# How to run a file that uses django models (large block of code) in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

So I have a chunk of code that declares some classes, creates data, uses django to actually save them to the database. My question is how do I actually execute it?

I am using PyCharm and have the file open. But I have no clue how to actually execute it. I can execute line by line in Django Console, but if it's more than that it can't handle the indentation.

The project itself runs fine (127.0.0.1 loads my page). How can I accomplish this?

I am sorry if this a completely obvious answer, I've been struggling with this for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site loads, you should put the import the models into one of your Django views.
In a view you can do whatever you like with the models.

Answer (score 1):

This [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/877/) named `Command Line Script Launcher` may help you,

> This snippet allows you execute arbitrary Python scripts from the command line 
>   with the context of a given project:
>
> python manage.py execfile /path/to/some/script.py

The doc of Django tells you how to [extend manage.py commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Comment: manage.py commands are the right place for one-off scripts that require Django settings / models. An excerpt from the docs linked above: "Custom management commands are especially useful for running standalone scripts..."

Answer (score 0):

You can right click any python file in pycharm and run it, though executing a script file self contained, you might want to add the main trick:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   do_stuff()
```